# Combine dataframes with custom indices and overlapping columns

Tags: pandas

I want to combine two dataframes with custom indices and potentially(but not gauranteed) overlapping columns. For overlapping columns, if there is a collision (same index both dfs have values), i want to take the value of the right df. If columns are completely distinct just take the union of the columns and replace values with nan as appropriate

Ex:

`df1:
       'fruit'   'vehicle'   'plant'
'abc'   apple     truck       tree
'def'   orange    car         bush
'ghi'   peach     bike        shrub`

`df2:
       'fruit'    'phone' 
'ghi'   plum       android`

Result would be:

`result:
       'fruit'   'vehicle'   'plant'   'phone'
'abc'   apple     truck       tree     'nan'
'def'   orange    car         bush     'nan'
'ghi'   plum     bike        shrub    'android'`

I've played around with join/merge, but can't seem to get my use case working.(End up with _x and _y on column names etc) Keeping the indices are compulsory as well (the 'abc', 'def', 'ghi')

Is this possible?

Comment: `df2.combine_first(df1)`

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i needed!